# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Expired

Tags: sql-server-2012

I've been working on this ASP.Net Project for a few months, and today my SQL Server 2012 Management Studio has expired. Completely overlooked that i may have been using a trial version and not the express edition. I can not access SQL management studio as it says the evaluation has expired.

1. Is there a way i can downgrade to the express edition (Free), without losing any databases?
2. Is there a way i can still backup/export the database i have been working on? Ive tried using the import/export 64 bit tool, but ive forgotten my sql server password. I had just been using the default all this time.

Thanks

Comment: Might a better option be to purchase the Developer Edition of SQL Server - if you need funcationality that may be lost by downgrading to Express Edition?

Comment: nope, i don't need the functionality, which may be lost by downgrading.

Comment: I just want to know how i can downgrade to express edition and still keep my database.

Comment: Sure you can - just uninstall your current trial version (shouldn't remove any database) - install the Express version **with tools** (to get SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express), and then re-attach your `.mdf` (data) and `.ldf` (log) files to that new Express instance....

Comment: Reattach my .mdf files? Sql server was using .dbo files? Where can i find these? So i know how to re-attach them when i come to install the express edition. And could you explain why unsinatlling sql server would not remove any databases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Backup database: You can get close backup of your databases by copying the data and log files from your Data directory. You can do this just using Windows copy and paste command.
2. Re-install from trail version: I faced this problem for SQL Server 2008 trial version. When SQL Server 2008 expired, I was able to re-install it as follows:

   a) Remove or uninstall all tools of SQL Server completely from Control Panel > Programs and Features.
   b) Then, re-install SQL Server as a new fresh tool.
   c) After completing the installation successfully, Cope and paste those backup data and log files into new data directory of new installation.
   d) Open SQL Server Mgmt Studio and attach the data file to re-create your old database. Your database will be resumed in this way.

I believe you can do this procedure for your SQL Server 2012 trial version too.

Comment: Where can i find these database log files?

Comment: How would installing the same trial copy help? Won't i need to do a fresh install of the express edition?

Comment: Please tell me in ur answer where i can find these .dbo files and log files

Comment: You can find these files in :\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\\(version of SQL)\MSSQL\Data folder. Your data directory may be different. Please note data file extension is MDF and log file extension is LDF. You can search using MDF or LDF on your directories.

Comment: Thank you, i found them both.

Comment: Just downloading then uninstalling SQL Server. Then will reinstall the express edition. I will tick answer wants my problem is fixed, as i don't want to create a new question if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Help! i put my .mdf database file and log file back into the new data folder, but when i go on sql management studio they don't show up? Am i missing something?